# How to restrict type assignment to type only ignoring the type it consists of

Tags: typescript

I have these two types:

```
type FooId = string
type BarId = string
```

I use it wherever I want to inform about what type of string I expect there.

Due to the nature of TS I can still do something like this:

```
const foo1: FooId = "bar" 
const foo1: FooId = "bar" as FooId
const foo2: FooId = "bar" as BarId;
```

**Is it possible forbid the third assignment, only, somehow?** (or even to forbid also the first, but still allow the second)

I want to avoid that `BarId` values can be used as `FooId` values (and vice versa).

Answer (score -1):

Not in this way.

`type` is like an alias, you are creating two alias to `string`.

If you know that `FooId` could only be some string, maybe `foo` and `bar`, you should use unions with literals

```js
type FooId = "bar" | "foo"
```

For more specific use, try [template strings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)